# I3 systray refuses to run

Tags: i3-window-manager

I'm going nuts and hope someone can help. I can't get the system tray to work on i3bar (or any other panel under i3 for that matter - tried tint2, mate-panel and neither showed the tray).

Infos:

- Using a recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 MATE
- Compiled & Installed i3-gaps (though I tried this with regular i3 too from repos on another clean Ubuntu 18.10 MATE installation, same situation, and also from a clean ubuntu install using regular i3 - no systray)
- i3 config, xrandr outputs and i3 debug info below.
- I'm just getting started in using i3, so maybe I'm missing something that could be obvious
- nm-applet is installed

I have tried REMOVING the tray_output line altogether (as shown in the config I pasted), I've tried 'tray_output primary' (ensuring one of the displays was in fact set as primary) and 'tray_output DVI-I-1' to no avail.

I see in i3bar debug output that I got by following instructions here: https://i3wm.org/docs/debugging.html and don't see any errors. All I do see is "Initializing system tray functionality" ... Great! So.... where is it?

I also just now tried specifying 'tray_output none' in the config file and got no corresponding "Initializing system tray functionality" so I know that the config file is in fact being read in that regard.

Any help that can be given is appreciated, thanks!

```
# This file has been auto-generated by i3-config-wizard(1).
# It will not be overwritten, so edit it as you like.
#
# Should you change your keyboard layout some time, delete
# this file and re-run i3-config-wizard(1).
#



# lock screen
bindsym $mod+l exec /home/riley/bin/ghettoblurlock

##scratchpad is kinda interesting

# Make the currently focused window a scratchpad
bindsym $mod+Shift+minus move scratchpad

# Show the first scratchpad window
bindsym $mod+minus scratchpad show

# gaps
for_window [class="^.*"] border pixel 3
smart_gaps on
smart_borders on
gaps inner 5
gaps outer 3

# Gaps mode

set $mode_gaps Gaps: (o) outer, (i) inner

set $mode_gaps_outer Outer Gaps: +|-|0 (local), Shift + +|-|0 (global)

set $mode_gaps_inner Inner Gaps: +|-|0 (local), Shift + +|-|0 (global)

bindsym $mod+Shift+g mode "$mode_gaps"



mode "$mode_gaps" {

        bindsym o      mode "$mode_gaps_outer"

        bindsym i      mode "$mode_gaps_inner"

        bindsym Return mode "default"

        bindsym Escape mode "default"

}


mode "$mode_gaps_inner" {

        bindsym plus  gaps inner current plus 5

        bindsym minus gaps inner current minus 5

        bindsym 0     gaps inner current set 0



        bindsym Shift+plus  gaps inner all plus 5

        bindsym Shift+minus gaps inner all minus 5

        bindsym Shift+0     gaps inner all set 0



        bindsym Return mode "default"

        bindsym Escape mode "default"

}



mode "$mode_gaps_outer" {

        bindsym plus  gaps outer current plus 5

        bindsym minus gaps outer current minus 5

        bindsym 0     gaps outer current set 0



        bindsym Shift+plus  gaps outer all plus 5

        bindsym Shift+minus gaps outer all minus 5

        bindsym Shift+0     gaps outer all set 0



        bindsym Return mode "default"

        bindsym Escape mode "default"

}

# i3 config file (v4)
#
# Please see https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!

set $mod Mod4

# Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
# is used in the bar {} block below.
font pango:monospace 8

# This font is widely installed, provides lots of unicode glyphs, right-to-left
# text rendering and scalability on retina/hidpi displays (thanks to pango).
#font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 8

# Before i3 v4.8, we used to recommend this one as the default:
# font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1
# The font above is very space-efficient, that is, it looks good, sharp and
# clear in small sizes. However, its unicode glyph coverage is limited, the old
# X core fonts rendering does not support right-to-left and this being a bitmap
# font, it doesn’t scale on retina/hidpi displays.

# Use Mouse+$mod to drag floating windows to their wanted position
floating_modifier $mod

# start a terminal
bindsym $mod+Return exec tilix

# kill focused window
bindsym $mod+Shift+q kill

# start dmenu (a program launcher)
# bindsym $mod+d exec dmenu_run
# There also is the (new) i3-dmenu-desktop which only displays applications
# shipping a .desktop file. It is a wrapper around dmenu, so you need that
# installed.
bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym $mod+Left focus left
bindsym $mod+Down focus down
bindsym $mod+Up focus up
bindsym $mod+Right focus right

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym $mod+Shift+Left move left
bindsym $mod+Shift+Down move down
bindsym $mod+Shift+Up move up
bindsym $mod+Shift+Right move right

# split in horizontal orientation
bindsym $mod+h split h

# split in vertical orientation
bindsym $mod+v split v

# enter fullscreen mode for the focused container
bindsym $mod+f fullscreen toggle

# change container layout (stacked, tabbed, toggle split)
bindsym $mod+s layout stacking
bindsym $mod+w layout tabbed
bindsym $mod+e layout toggle split

# toggle tiling / floating
bindsym $mod+Shift+space floating toggle

# change focus between tiling / floating windows
bindsym $mod+space focus mode_toggle

# focus the parent container
bindsym $mod+a focus parent

# focus the child container
#bindsym $mod+d focus child

# Define names for default workspaces for which we configure key bindings later on.
# We use variables to avoid repeating the names in multiple places.
set $ws1 "1"
set $ws2 "2"
set $ws3 "3"
set $ws4 "4"
set $ws5 "5"
set $ws6 "6"
set $ws7 "7"
set $ws8 "8"
set $ws9 "9"
set $ws10 "10"

# switch to workspace
bindsym $mod+1 workspace $ws1
bindsym $mod+2 workspace $ws2
bindsym $mod+3 workspace $ws3
bindsym $mod+4 workspace $ws4
bindsym $mod+5 workspace $ws5
bindsym $mod+6 workspace $ws6
bindsym $mod+7 workspace $ws7
bindsym $mod+8 workspace $ws8
bindsym $mod+9 workspace $ws9
bindsym $mod+0 workspace $ws10

# move focused container to workspace
bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace $ws1
bindsym $mod+Shift+2 move container to workspace $ws2
bindsym $mod+Shift+3 move container to workspace $ws3
bindsym $mod+Shift+4 move container to workspace $ws4
bindsym $mod+Shift+5 move container to workspace $ws5
bindsym $mod+Shift+6 move container to workspace $ws6
bindsym $mod+Shift+7 move container to workspace $ws7
bindsym $mod+Shift+8 move container to workspace $ws8
bindsym $mod+Shift+9 move container to workspace $ws9
bindsym $mod+Shift+0 move container to workspace $ws10

# reload the configuration file
bindsym $mod+Shift+c reload
# restart i3 inplace (preserves your layout/session, can be used to upgrade i3)
bindsym $mod+Shift+r restart
# exit i3 (logs you out of your X session)
bindsym $mod+Shift+e exec "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -B 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit'"

# resize window (you can also use the mouse for that)
mode "resize" {
        # These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the resize mode

        # Pressing left will shrink the window’s width.
        # Pressing right will grow the window’s width.
        # Pressing up will shrink the window’s height.
        # Pressing down will grow the window’s height.
        bindsym j resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym k resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym l resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym semicolon resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        # same bindings, but for the arrow keys
        bindsym Left resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Down resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Up resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Right resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        # back to normal: Enter or Escape or $mod+r
        bindsym Return mode "default"
        bindsym Escape mode "default"
        bindsym $mod+r mode "default"
}

bindsym $mod+r mode "resize"

# Start i3bar to display a workspace bar (plus the system information i3status
# finds out, if available)
bar {
    verbose yes
    status_command i3status
}


# AUTOSTARTS

exec --no-startup-id nm-applet &
exec --no-startup-id blueman-applet
```

```
riley@riley-desktop:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 297mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    29.97    23.98    60.05    60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
riley@riley-desktop:~$ i3 reload
03/24/2019 10:14:08 AM - Additional arguments passed. Sending them as a command to i3.
[{"success":true}]
riley@riley-desktop:~$ killall i3bar
riley@riley-desktop:~$ for c in $(i3-msg -t get_bar_config | python -c \
>       'import json,sys;print("\n".join(json.load(sys.stdin)))'); do \
>     (i3bar --bar_id=$c >i3bar.$c.log 2>&1) & \
>   done;
[1] 7431
riley@riley-desktop:~$ cat i3bar.bar-0.log 
i3status: trying to auto-detect output_format setting
i3status: auto-detection: parent process is "sh", looking at its parent
i3status: auto-detected "i3bar"
[libi3] ../../i3-gaps/libi3/font.c Using Pango font monospace, size 8
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1278] Calculated font-height: 13
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1423] Setting bar_fg = #FFFFFF as _NET_SYSTEM_TRAY_COLORS
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1060] Received X11 error, sequence 0x26, error_code = 3
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/ipc.c:217] Got data!
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/ipc.c:66] Clearing old output configuration...
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/ipc.c:69] Parsing outputs JSON...
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/ipc.c:71] Reconfiguring windows...
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1668] Creating window for output HDMI-0
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1663] Destroying window for output xroot-0
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1668] Creating window for output DVI-I-1
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1330] Initializing system tray functionality
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1423] Setting bar_fg = #FFFFFF as _NET_SYSTEM_TRAY_COLORS
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1897] Drawing bars...
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1907] Output xroot-0 inactive, skipping...
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/ipc.c:217] Got data!
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/ipc.c:57] Got subscribe reply: {"success":true}
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/ipc.c:217] Got data!
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/ipc.c:46] Got workspace data!
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/workspaces.c:143] Got workspace canonical: 1, name: '1', name_width: 6, glyphs: 1
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/workspaces.c:143] Got workspace canonical: 2, name: '2', name_width: 6, glyphs: 1
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1897] Drawing bars...
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1924] Drawing button for WS 2 at x = 0, len = 6
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1907] Output xroot-0 inactive, skipping...
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1924] Drawing button for WS 1 at x = 0, len = 6
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:454] Detecting input type based on buffer *{"version":1}
[
[{"name":"ipv6","color":"#FF0000","markup":"none","full_text":"no IPv6"},{"name":"disk_info","instance":"/","markup":"none","full_text":"41.3 GiB"},{"name":"wireless","instance":"_first_","color":"#FF0000","markup":"none","full_text":"W: down"},{"name":"ethernet","instance":"enp3s0","color":"#00FF00","markup":"none","full_text":"E: 10.1.0.0 (1000 Mbit/s)"},{"name":"battery","markup":"none","full_text":"No battery"},{"name":"load","markup":"none","full_text":"0.14"},{"name":"tztime","instance":"local","markup":"none","full_text":"2019-03-24 10:14:18"}]
*
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:327] copying statusline_buffer to statusline_head
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:331] dumping statusline:
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:334] full_text = no IPv6
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:335] short_text = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:336] color = #FF0000
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:334] full_text = 41.3 GiB
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:335] short_text = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:336] color = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:334] full_text = W: down
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:335] short_text = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:336] color = #FF0000
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:334] full_text = E: 10.1.0.0 (1000 Mbit/s)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:335] short_text = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:336] color = #00FF00
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:334] full_text = No battery
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:335] short_text = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:336] color = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:334] full_text = 0.14
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:335] short_text = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:336] color = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:334] full_text = 2019-03-24 10:14:18
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:335] short_text = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:336] color = (null)
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/child.c:338] end of dump
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1897] Drawing bars...
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1924] Drawing button for WS 2 at x = 0, len = 6
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:2000] Printing statusline!
[../../i3-gaps/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1907] Output xroot-0 inactive, skipping.
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying an [output](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_output_s) (not `tray_output`)?

Comment: Hm, interesting. I've already got i3bar on all outputs which is what the 'output' directive does inside of a bar{} block but maybe I could play with that and see if I can get it to do something different.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misread the question. I thought you couldn't get the i3bar to run.